# input boxes shape restricted by parent div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve the look for my login area similar to this photo.

[image]

My current HTML and CSS are as follows:
HTML

```
<div className="loginArea">
    <p>Account Login</p>
    <div className="inputBoxes">
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Sign In</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
      .loginArea {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputBoxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.inputBoxes div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
}
```

My goal is to achieve the styling of this input area with respect to the shape of the inputs/sign in button as what look like one rectangle with rounded corners.

The problems I'm running into are two fold:

1. I can't seem to restrict the size of the input areas to the parent container. They run outside the parent div.
2. I can't seem to get the input areas to accept the restricted border-radius of the parent container.

Do I have to style each element individually for the rounded borders and how do I restrict the username and password areas to the width of the parent div?

If there are "better" approaches, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using flexbox, the input element sizes seem to correctly fit inside the confines of the parents without any issue.

With regards to your second issue, adding `overflow: hidden` to the element `.inputBoxes` will work.

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.loginArea {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inputBoxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inputBoxes div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  height: 35px; /* Just for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="loginArea">
  <p>Account Login</p>
  <div class="inputBoxes">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Sign In</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```